# Why do we need curl for authorize.net libraries?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, authorize.net

I want to integrate the authorize.net API in my CodeIgniter project, and after some research,  i found a library on Github called [SammyK/codeigniter-authorize.net-aim-api](https://github.com/SammyK/codeigniter-authorize.net-aim-api). This library requires the use of **curl**.

As far as I know, **curl** is a library that you turn on on your PHP.INI, so do i have install that as package on linux machine? What is it used for? Is there any other library that works better for the Authorize.net API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so do I have install that as package on Linux machine ?

You can also install curl in windows - http://curl.haxx.se/download.html and you can load the php-curl module in windows too.

Got to `c:\php\php.ini (it can be different path in your computer) and uncomment`

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

> What is the use ?

CURL is a command line tool for getting or sending files using URL syntax. Supports the follow protocols HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, FTPS, SCP, SFTP, TFTP, LDAP, LDAPS, DICT, TELNET, FILE, IMAP, POP3, SMTP and RTSP (the last four only in versions newer than 7.20.0 or 9 February 2010).

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL

> any library better work for Authorize.net API ?

https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php